# when i install AFNetworking using CocoaPods i get following error when i hit "$ pod install" command

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

when i install AFNetworking using CocoaPods i get following error when I hit 
`$ pod install` command
error is

> "YOU NEED AT LEAST GIT VERSION 1.8.5 TO USE COCOAPODS"

[image]

Comment: So... What version of git do you have? Do you have it at all?

Answer (score 1):

You have to right now this command in terminal

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Answer (score 0):

Check git version by executing in terminal:

```
git --version
```

You can update/install git from here:
https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Answer (score 0):

You have to download git version from here and Install it

https://git-scm.com/download/mac

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are facing this problem because your git version is older.

If you have installed Xcode (Xcode has the latest git built-in ), so you only need the terminal type:

```
sudo Xcode - select - switch/Applications /[your Xcode application name.app]
```

so that you can use the Xcode built-in git